# Getting a force close error on receipt of a text message AFTER app has been killed

Tags: android, sms

Have an app that carries out a number of tasks when the phone receives on sms message, and they all work fine.  However, if I exit/ kill the app, I get a force close error when I receive an sms message.

It's almost like the app is still somehow running/ some methods like "onReceive" are still cached in memory.  I need to ensure when the application is exited, that it is properly exited and the phone doesn't give the force close error. 
Can anyone advise?

Here is the code for exiting the app which seems to work fine.  (When I press back on the phone when inside the app and am back at android home screen, when I check advanced task killer; it is not listed)

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();

    System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);


    System.exit(0);
}//end onDestroy method
```

Comment: See the answer from dziobas - an Activity is not the 'app'. When an Activity ends it doesn't mean the app (Application) has been terminated. Learn how Android works with respect to Applications, Activities, BroadcastReceivers and Services work and it will probably answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look at the system logs (adb logcat) there may be some messages about not unregistered/leaked recievers or something else similar.

Looks like you have some reciever that rely on some data, what was destroyed/nulled after your app shutdown.

Why are you doing System.exit(0)? Also `runFinalizersOnExit` is marked deprecated and unsafe in documentation.

Seems like you need to do `unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver)` in `onStop` or `onDestroy` method depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks.  I am unsure still why it crashes after the app has been killed.  i.imgur.com/8QI8f.png (here is link to logcat) just notcied that is depreciated myself.  I commented it out.  Surely with advanced task killer app, that should stop the app fully? hmmm... think I need to do some more reading about how android assigns tasks.

Comment: I think you need not to force full stop of the app by yourself. Doing so may cause the errors like you are facing now. Android OS must decide whenever or not to kill your app. Remember what not only your activity is living in app process, but also receivers and services (if not declared as external).

Comment: thanks Olegas, but I need away somehow to stop the force close error anyway.  To be able to ignore whats causing it to stop it from happening.

Comment: Get a error log from a device just after the "force close error" - what is causing it? What line, what class, what exception? If you are saying the issue at the screenshot above is fixed, i think it is not the last one if it still crashing.

Comment: It still crashes after "apparent" exit.  Although that line claims to be a problem, the functionality of it during run time is perfect.  But it definately is some issue with this line, cause it keeps giving same error on logcat when I receive a text, & force close error is displayed.  However, as I said, this code does exactly what I expect it to do during run time!

Comment: Check the failing line! The code here is doing something with objects that are NULL. And they become null after your app is killed. Look at the code, get to know what objects are used in the failing line and then add some debugging there (may be through the `Log.d` or smth else). If you get what objects are nulled here, you can determine what is destroying them. Also, show some code, exactly the failing lines.

Comment: SpeakerActivity:   public static void speakSMSfrom(String msgfrom){
                //myTts.speak(msgfrom, 0, null);
    myTts.speak(msgfrom, 1, null);
   }//end speakSMS method

Comment: Well, there is nothing to be null except myTts. What is it? Where it is created? How long is it's lifecycle? Where it is destroyed?

Comment: The line in the other class is: if(displayName.equals("")){
    FYPSpeakerActivity.speakSMSorigin(origin);
    }else{//end if
    FYPSpeakerActivity.speakSMSorigin(displayName); 
    }//end nested if
    FYPSpeakerActivity.speakSMS0(sms0);

Comment: I will show you clearer. http://pastebin.com/2SHBdyfx  (the comments to show problem line are NOT in the actual code, just here to explain)

Comment: The second problem line is wrong, its actually this line:     FYPSpeakerActivity.speakSMSfrom(msgfrom);

Comment: I'm still repeating my question... What is `myTts`, where it is declared and when it is destroyed?

Comment: myTts is a new TextToSpeech object. (myTts = new TextToSpeech(this, ttsInitListener);) it is declared inside the oncreate method of the speakeractivity class.  I never destroy it.  I think this is my problem?

Comment: I don't think it would benefit.  I think I need to rephrase my question.  Ideally all I need to know is howto ensure pressing the back button on the phone ends the app, and closes all running activities and anything that maybe in memory.  I am aware the OS will always have more control over this than I can, so perhaps catching the exception is the route I need to take.

Comment: So, you need to unregister your reciever, which is triggering speakSMSfrom(String).

Comment: Yeah, do not know how. :( I will have to do more research so I understand how the activity lifecycle works I think.  It's a very frustrating error, because IF it was fixed, the app would run perfectly. It's the only bug at the moment!

Comment: you need to do `unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver)` in `onDestroy` or `onStop` method, depending on your needs.

Comment: Olegas, I don't seem to actually register the receiver in the first place.  The class I use it in extends Broadcast receiver, but I have only an onCreate method and another small, get method.  The onCreate method has almost 300 lines of code. :-\ I think the registration thing maybe the problem alright, but I think my code structure for that particular class is creating problems all on it's own!

Answer (score 3):

You should read some about how Android works:

- [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) especially Activity Lifecycle part
- [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html)
- [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Answer (score 1):

It seems quite obvious that it is FYPSpeakerActivity has a null value in there. But based on your description, that probably should not ever be called.

How are you registering for text messages? 
If you are using manifest.xml to define the broadcast receivers for text messages, then "Exiting" your app does nothing to prevent those.
If you are registering the broadcast receiver programatically, then you will need to unregister at some point. "Exiting" the app does not automatically unregister.

Furthermore, as in other posts you should read up on the application lifecycle. System.exit() is frowned upon, runFinalizerOnExit is deprecated, and onDestroy is not guaranteed to run.

Comment: Some very useful information, thank you.  What is best method for ensuring the broadcast receivers is unregistered?  Here is line in manifest file where I have it mentioned:  <receiver android:name="FYPSmsReceiverBroadcast"  android:configChanges="orientation" android:orientation="vertical" android:enabled="true">
      <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/> 
     </intent-filter>
     </receiver>

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html Look into there. Specifically at public abstract void setComponentEnabledSetting (ComponentName componentName, int newState, int flags)...         Your goal should be to disable the receiver when you want the app to "exit"